# Unable to access private members when redefining method of class

Tags: javascript, typescript

When defining a private member using `#`, and then re-defining some member that uses this private member, you will find that you cannot use it anymore:

```js
class Foo {
    #secret = "Keyboard Cat";
    
    method() {
        console.log(this.#secret);
    }
}

const target = Foo.prototype;
const key = "method";

const desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key);

const og = desc.value;

desc.value = function (...args) {
    return og.apply(target, args);
};

Object.defineProperty(target, key, desc);

new Foo().method();
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read private member #secret from an object whose class did not declare it

Why? All I have done is wrap around the original method in this case. Note that this example is a dramatic simplification of using decorators with TypeScript. How could I get around this while still being able to redefine and "change" the method?

---

Here's the same thing, but with a TypeScript decorator:

```
const Curse: MethodDecorator = (target, _, desc) => {
    const og = desc.value as Function;

    desc.value = function (...args: any[]) {
        return og.apply(target, args);
    } as any;

    return desc;
};

class Foo {
    #secret = "Keyboard Cat";
    
    @Curse
    method() {
        console.log(this.#secret);
    }
}

new Foo().method();
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAwgVwE4QKYC4YFlVQBYgAmAIqqEgIZQhIwC8MAFFBUgOa4A0MA+t4agjAAlPQB8MAN4BYAFAwFMUJFgg29GAKEA6AG4UANglQwKEGADEEYYFACW4ANxy5izYOB7DxjQDNrtg5gTNqhrGwQmBRgAJ4A2gC6ojLybopIuMjBatoUAA55BjHM4Vym7BDCzqkKAL6m5tEx1a7pmUjBWsDVtS2ywAZm5hYgIFKtCgDEaMAZsAwARADSqDEARiCshPBUC9VuEzAAAogoqIcAtrgEhIzJh27KECAGqNoGasx4dhDa02RzKqHWpyEGyORgVAAd0sozu2iu+CId0cQA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake you made is to apply the method to the `target`, which is `Foo.prototype`, not to the `new Foo` instance via the `this` keyword:

```js
class Foo {
    #secret = "Keyboard Cat";
    
    method() {
        console.log(this.#secret);
    }
}

const target = Foo.prototype;
const key = "method";

const desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key);

const orig = desc.value;

desc.value = function (...args) {
    return orig.apply(this, args);
//                    ^^^^
};

Object.defineProperty(target, key, desc);

new Foo().method();
```

`Foo.prototype` does not have the `#secret` private field. You'll get the same error with

```js
class Foo {
    #secret = "Keyboard Cat";
    
    method() {
        console.log(this.#secret);
    }
}

Foo.prototype.method();
```

Comment: Ah of course... I tested with the TypeScript example as well and it solves my problem. Thanks.